# C# Windows Form and SQL server

Tags: c#

I created a login form which is connect to SQL server which run in my computer very well but when i try try to install the installer pack in another computer it shows "Unhandled exception has occurred in your appplication ...........

A network related of instance specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server. the server was not found or was not accseeible .........."

when i can connect sql server from another using VS is connected that show sql server can be establish from but my installer pack(software) has somthing wrong
when i install in my computer tn work but in another comuter it not work

```
connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-T6L7KFD\SQLEXPRESS2016,49172; Initial Catalog=CC;User ID=sa;Password=mypc107" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to update your connnectionstring as per another machine !!!

Comment: How ?? plz explain in bit detail

Comment: There should be App.Config file which has that connectionstring setting. You can update that connectionstring

Comment: I know but what should be new connection string ??

Comment: How do i determin new connection string

Comment: It has to point to server

Comment: You have to find out, what's your machine name, credential. So, I can't say it precisely without having idea about your machne

Comment: can u expain me by taking an example ?

Comment: what is the ",49172" in your Data Source for?

Comment: if your server name is "THESERVER" then your connection string would be connectionString="Data Source=THESERVER; Initial Catalog=CC;User ID=sa;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: @phishfordead is correct, you only need the \SQLEXPRESS2016 if you are running multiple instances of Sql Server at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change connectionString="Data Source=**DESKTOP-T6L7KFD\SQLEXPRESS2016**, to the directory where the file is on the computer. The best would be if you deploy the database on a server or in **DEBUG** folder of your application

Comment: the file is on the server